# Positioning issue in Chrome (other browsers work fine)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-float

I have made 3 screenshots to explain it, please see all 3 and then click on my last link:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, Chrome is pushing element #4 (class=".newsline2") down.

Firefox & IE9 display this flawlessly.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
.newsline2 { position: absolute; right:0; top:0; }
```

instead of `float:right` that you're currently using.

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed it in combination with the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

When the element is absolute it needs proper width and height along with top-bottom-left-right positions. Add `height: 16px` instead of auto. It will work in Chrome too.

Comment: Your answer was appreciated and used, however it did not fix the positioning problem of element 4. alexg's method did fix that issue. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Add height to  CSS rule ".contentContainer h2" as follows

```
.contentContainer h2 {
height: 16px;
...
...
}
```

Comment: Your answer was appreciated and used, however it did not fix the positioning problem of element 4. alexg's method did fix that issue. Thank you for the help!